# extract whole paragraph containing keyword from pdf of novel

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, apache-tika, pypdf

I'm trying to analyze a novel by focusing on passages containing a specific keyword, like paragraphs containing the word "thought" or "night." What I have so far isn't working.

```
import tika
from tika import parser
parsed = parser.from_file('ethanfrome22.pdf')
keyword = ['thought']
if keyword in parsed["content"]:
    print(parsed["content"])'
```

Answer (score 0):

I never used tika but from the looks try to lookup the string `thought` instead of the whole list, e.g. change code to:

```
import tika
from tika import parser

parsed = parser.from_file('ethanfrome22.pdf')
keywords = ['thought', 'or', 'two']

for keyword in keywords:
    if keyword in parsed["content"]:
        print(parsed["content"])
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: thank you, although it's still printing the whole text. i think maybe somewhere in the print statement.. not sure

Comment: I also tried unsuccessfully with pypdf2 I can post that one in another question